# Apache 2.4 - How to redirect images to a php file?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I need to redirect all images to a php file, including the path and file name.

Imagine my domain is example.com
I might have https://example.com/art/logo.png and want to do redirect this to https://example.com/scripts/image_loader.php?a:art&b=logo.png

So, I would force any request to be redirected to a php-file which will display the image. I am doing this to control who can access the images and also to prevent hotlinking.
I also want html-files to use this redirect and use the php file to display the image, e.g. for included 'img src=/art/logo.png'

I already did the mod_rewrite using the referral header method but it's not working and I am not sure why. I am assuming that the https protocol doesn't use a referrer in the header.

For the php I need to know how I can stop someone from hotlinking my images and from just downloading them as files. 
Can I determine if the user is a person or a bot or some kind of site ripper?

I know I can't stop a person from downloading images. I just want to make it harder for them. So, they cannot just easily download them or use a site ripper software.

Any suggestions would be great. My website uses or runs on HTTPS. A lot of solutions for hotlinking online only shows examples using http.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Can you determine wether the request is from a user or a bot?**

NYeah, more or less^^ You can use the UserAgent-Header field to determine if the request was sent via a browser or not. But then the question is do you want to blacklist all site-rippers (like HTTrack) or whitelist all common Browsers? Both will be an incomplete and pretty long list.

**2. How to rewrite all images to your php-file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectRule ^/(.+/(.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|tif|bmp))$ /scripts/image_loader.php?a:$1&b=$2
```

This rewrites all requests for standard-images, if the called URI-pattern follows your specified '/path/image.png' to /scripts/image_loader.php?a:path&b=image.png

**update**

```
RedirectRule ^^/(.+/)+(.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|tif|bmp))$ /scripts/image_loader.php?a:$1&b=$2
```

The first bracket `(.+)` includes the part after the servername up to the last file name, so in the example `/path/example/image.png` it would contain `path/example`. The second bracket `(.+)` only includes the file name, so in the example `/path/example/image.png` it would contain `image.png`. Now both values are assigned to the target-URL -->

```
/scripts/image_loader.php?a:path/example&b=image.png
```

Hopefully I got your question right...

Comment: Did you already try that suggestion? Just saw that you accepted my 'edit' so thought you might tested it ;)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but got a question for the part of a:$1&b=$2 what is $1 and $2 like how's the values getting assigned to that? I need to grab the directory and file name of the image. To then pass it to a php file. so the art in this example is a folder in the site and the logo.png is the file.  i have 2 variables for the php file to get the folder paths after the root folder and then the 2nd var is the file name.

Comment: I think it makes sense but what if the url is like /app1/images/logo.png  something like that. Would this still work?  would it grab /app1/images and put it as $1 for the php script variable a?  because a is for the directory path and b is filename.  I don't want it to be static like /path/logo.png  For a it would grab path and if /path/folder2/apple.jpg  I would want a to contain path/folder2/  and b is apple.jpg  I just want to clarify to make sure it would work how I want it to work. a should be dynamic no matter how many folders there is in the path.

Comment: But the last two are always the path and filename that should be added as parameters? like `/some/random/path/images/image.png` ?

Comment: Yeah, for example if   we go to example.com/art/logo.png   or example/path1/pumpkinpic/pumpkin1.png

Comment: should do that now ;)

Comment: Yeah, for example if   we go to example.com/art/logo.png   or example/path1/pumpkinpic/pumpkin1.png            I want A to contain  art/  or  path1/pumpkinpic/   so, A for the PHP file is going to pass in the path from root to the directory where the image is located.  B will contain the file name.  If  the file is in root folder like example.com/logo.png then A will contain nothing but B will contain the file logo.png

Comment: Root as in  example.com/      So, a  will contain anything after example.com./  and the actual file. So, if example.com/logo.png or  example.com/art/logo.png or  example.com/art/pic_pumkings/logo.png  The A will contain everything after example.com/  and before logo.png including the last /  in the path. B will just contain the file name.

Comment: ahhh, k, gimme as sec. hopefully i now understood correctly how you want it to work :D